# How do I set a site as ROOT on Apache 2.2?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, configuration

**UPDATE:** -- **bindbn:** Try change DocumentRoot in (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) to (DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/drupal") -- **@bindbn:** That didn't work. One question I have is is does the "www" folder have some meaning to Apache, since I've currently got the install here. "/var/www/drupal" instead of here "/var/www/html/drupal" -- Also, after I made the suggested change I ran the CMDs "# httpd -k stop" then "# apachectl start" as sudo, are those correct?

---

**Context:** First time using Apache, and followed the default install directions for a CMS called Drupal.

**Problem** is that now the install is not root, meaning in the case of www.sample.com, it would be running at www.sample.com/drupal, not at www.sample.com; which is where I need it.

**Googled** all this, searched serverfault questions, and I'm still completely lost; also, I really don't want to mess up an Apache config doing the wrong thing; plus, appears Apache config mods change a lot version to version. Thanks in advance for any pointers!!

**INFO:** Apache-2.2, CentOS-5.5

If you have any questions, just let me know -- again, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change DocumentRoot in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/drupal"
```

Comment: **@bindbn:** That didn't work. One question I have is is does the "www" folder have some meaning to Apache, since I've currently got the install here. "/var/www/drupal" instead of here "/var/www/html/drupal" -- Also, after I made the suggested change I ran the CMDs "# httpd -k stop" then "# apachectl start" as sudo, are those correct?

Comment: "www" has no special meaning other than being the default for a lot of distributions.  You may have more than one DocumentRoot if you're using a VirtualHost directive, each VirtualHost has its own DocumentRoot.

Comment: **@_All:** Not sure if it matters, but I also just set this as well. "<Directory "/var/www/drupal">" -- guessing the issue is that I'm not restarting Apache correctly, do I type "# apachectl start" or "apachectl start", because if it's the last one, I get this error "-bash: apachectl: command not found"

Comment: @blunders: it's probably `apache2ctl restart` you want to use to restart apache

Comment: **@Iain:** Yes, I've tried that too. If a restart was logged, where might the log file be located, and/or what would it's file name be. Strange thing is I enter the CMDs, pause for a sec, then return no error or confirmation. Should I get a confirmation on the success execution of the command?

Comment: **@bindbn:** 100% sure that's the right answer, something else is going on, thanks for the quick reply! Cheers!